# Excel Formula for finding Y maximum in a given X range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an XY table in excel. I would like to find the maximum Y value in a given X range. Example data given below. What equation can I use, in an unrelated cell, to output the max Y value in between the X range 2:6

| X | Y |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 7 |
| 3 | 0 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 3 |

Answer (score 3):

Using `MAXIFS`:

```
=MAXIFS(B:B,A:A,">=2",A:A,"<=6")
```

[image]

As noted by @ScottCraner, if your version of Excel does not support `MAXIFS`, see [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/1312647/alternative-function-of-maxifs-minifs-in-excel) for alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question so:

you want the biggest number in column Y which also is present in X

```
=MAXIFS(B2:B7;B2:B7;">="&MIN(A2:A7);B2:B7;"<="&MAX(A2:A7))
```

[image]